# Error in sort function by 6 columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a function that copies and pastes info from one sheet to two others, then sorts all three sheets differently.  The first sheet is a simple alpha sort by column 1, the second sheet is an alpha sort by column 2, and the third sheet sorts by columns 3-8 in that order.  When data is edited on "Student list details" the user clicks the "SORT" button to run this script and modify all three pages.  However, the third page (AutoDocHeidiOnly2) is not sorting properly.  There is no error given, it appears to run fine, but the sheet is not sorted.

```
function myFunction() {

  //var copyFromRange = 'Student List Details!A3:H1000';

  //var copyToRangeStart = 'AutoDocHeidiOnly!A3:H1000';
   // copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart);

  var sld = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Student List Details");
  var ado = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AutoDocHeidiOnly");
  var ado2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AutoDocHeidiOnly2");
  var sourceRange=sld.getRange("A3:H1000");
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
  ado.getRange(3,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);
  ado2.getRange(3,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);
  var lastRow = sld.getLastRow()
   var range = sld.getRange(3,1,lastRow,9);
  range.sort(1);
  var lastRow = ado.getLastRow()
   var range = ado.getRange(3,1,lastRow,8);
  range.sort(2);
   var lastRow = ado2.getLastRow()
   var range = ado2.getRange(3,1,lastRow,8);
  range.sort({Column: 3},{Column: 4},{Column: 5},{Column: 6},{Column: 7},{Column: 8});
 // ado.getDataRange()

   // var rowssld = sld.getDataRange().getValues();
//  var ado2 = sheet.getSheets('AutoDocHeidiOnly2')

  //var row = sld.getRange(88, 3, 1, 9).getValues();



 // ado.appendRow(row[0]);

// var targetrange = ado.getRange(3, 1, sld.getLastRow(), 9);
  //var rangeValues = sld.getRange(3, 1, sld.getLastRow(), 9).getValues();
 //targetrange.setValues(rangeValues);
//for (var i = 3; i < rowssld.length; i++){
// for (var j = 1; j < 9; j++){
 //  var val=sld.getRange(i,j).getValue();
 //  ado.getRange(i,j).setValue(val);
 // }
 // }

  Browser.msgBox("FINISHED") ;  
}


function test()
{
   var sld = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Student List Details");
  var ado = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AutoDocHeidiOnly");
  var ado2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AutoDocHeidiOnly2");
  var sourceRange=sld.getRange("A3:H1000");
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
  ado.getRange(3,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);
  ado2.getRange(3,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);
  var lastRow = sld.getLastRow()
   var range = sld.getRange(3,1,lastRow,9);
  range.sort(1);
  var lastRow = ado.getLastRow()
   var range = ado.getRange(3,1,lastRow,8);
  range.sort(2);
   var lastRow = ado2.getLastRow()
   var range = ado2.getRange(3,1,lastRow,8);
  range.sort(3);
 // ado.getDataRange()

   // var rowssld = sld.getDataRange().getValues();
//  var ado2 = sheet.getSheets('AutoDocHeidiOnly2')

  //var row = sld.getRange(88, 3, 1, 9).getValues();



 // ado.appendRow(row[0]);

// var targetrange = ado.getRange(3, 1, sld.getLastRow(), 9);
  //var rangeValues = sld.getRange(3, 1, sld.getLastRow(), 9).getValues();
 //targetrange.setValues(rangeValues);
//for (var i = 3; i < rowssld.length; i++){
// for (var j = 1; j < 9; j++){
 //  var val=sld.getRange(i,j).getValue();
 //  ado.getRange(i,j).setValue(val);
 // }
 // }

  Browser.msgBox("FINISHED") ;  


}

//function copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart) {

//  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //var source = ss.getRange(copyFromRange);

  //source.copyTo(ss.getRange(copyToRangeStart), {contentsOnly: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a crack at this, but did you try specifying the ascending order for the columns on the 3rd sheet? For example:

```
 range.sort({Column: 3},{Column: 4},{Column: 5},{Column: 6},{Column: 7},{Column: 8});
```

Try:

```
 range.sort([{Column: 3, ascending: true},{Column: 4, ascending: true},{Column: 5, ascending: true},{Column: 6, ascending: true},{Column: 7, ascending: true},{Column: 8, ascending: true}]);
```

By no means am I one of the wizards on here, but I've ran into some funky issues myself, so just trying to be helpful! :)